# Python, numpy; How to best deal with possible 0d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python numpy ndarrays are failing me!  Can I go back to Matlab??

Let's say I have a function that is expecting a ndarray vector input.  I use the numpy.asarray function to force the inputs into the form I want, conveniently with no duplication for things that are already ndarrays.  However, if a scalar gets passed in, it is sometimes made into a 0d array instead of a 1d array, depending on exactly how it got passed in.  The 0d array causes issues, because I can index into it.

First off, why can't I?  Say `x = np.array(1)`.  Then `x.size == 1`, so it should have a 0th element.  Why can't I do `x[0]` or `x[-1]`.  I get that it wants to be *like* a python int, but it should be improved over an int, and not purposely given the same limitations.

Secondly, it would be awesome if the numpy asarray function had some optional input to force the output to always be at least a 1d array.  Then I could do something like `x = np.asarray(x, force_at_least_1d=True)`.

However, the best option I could come up with is to check the ndim property, and if it's 0, then expand it to 1.  This just feels wrong to me.  Is there some other option that I'm missing?

```
import numpy as np

def func(x, extra_check=True):
    r"""Meaningless Example Function for stackoverflow."""
    # force input to be ndarrays
    x = np.asarray(x)

    if x.size == 0:
        print('Don''t do anything.')

    # Extra test to deal with garbage 0D arrays so that they can be indexed by keep.
    # This test is really bothering me.  Is there a better way to make it unnecessary?
    if extra_check and (x.ndim == 0):
        x = x[np.newaxis]

    if x[0] > 0 and x[-1] > 5:
        print('Do something cool.')
    else:
        print('Do something less cool.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # nominally intended use
    x1 = np.array([1, 2, 10])
    y1 = func(x1) # prints "Do something cool."

    # single item use
    x2 = x1[x1 == 2]
    y2 = func(x2) # prints "Do something less cool."

    # scalar single item use that works with extra check
    x3 = x1[1]
    y3 = func(x3) # prints "Do something less cool."

    # scalar single item that will fail without extra check
    x4 = x1[1]
    y4 = func(x4, extra_check=False) # raises IndexError
```

So my main question here is whether there's a better way than what I have.  And If not, do others agree that there should be?  I'm relatively new to Python, so I've never tried to contribute anything to the source yet, but presumably I can look for another question that explains that process to me.

In case it matters, I'm on python v3.5.1 and numpy 1.9.3.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `np.array([[1]])` if you need a MATLAB like 2d array.  We use expressions like `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` all the time.

Comment: Personally I find numpy's treatment of 1D and 0D arrays to be one of it's biggest advantages over Matlab. It's all consistent. Indexing a 2D array can be done with a length-2 tuple. A 0D array? A length-0 tuple. It's lovely. If you are writing functions which operate on truly ND arrays, then the Matlab implementation becomes the one with all the special cases.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Secondly, it would be awesome if the numpy asarray function had some optional input to force the output to always be at least a 1d array. Then I could do something like x = np.asarray(x, force_at_least_1d=True).

`np.asarray` doesn't, but `np.array` does --`ndmin` -- and there's a dedicated `np.atleast_1d` function (also 2 and 3):

```
>>> np.array(0, ndmin=1)
array([0])
>>> np.atleast_1d(np.array(0))
array([0])
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll replace the `x = np.asarray(x)` with `x = np.atleast_1d(np.asarray(x))` and get rid of the extra check.  That seems like a reasonably clean approach for this.

Comment: `np.atleast_1d(x)` should be sufficient, as it automatically converts non `ndarray` inputs into an `ndarray` first.

Answer (score 10):

Any array can be indexed with a tuple with `x.ndim` elements

2d:

```
In [238]: x=np.array([[1]])
In [239]: x.ndim
Out[239]: 2
In [240]: x[(0,0)]   # same as x[0,0]
Out[240]: 1
```

1d:

```
In [241]: x=np.array([1])    
In [242]: x[(0,)]     # (0,) to distinguish from (0)==0
Out[242]: 1
```

0d:

```
In [243]: x=np.array(1)    
In [244]: x[()]      # empty tuple
Out[244]: 1
```

Indexing an element doesn't actually return a scalar

```
In [250]: x=np.array([[1]])

In [251]: type(x[0,0])
Out[251]: numpy.int32

In [252]: x[0,0][()]
Out[252]: array(1)
```

It returns a `dtype` object, which accepts 0d indexing.

You mention MATLAB. - there everything is 2d (or higher);  Isn't it more logical to set 0d as the lower bound?  :)

The other answer mentioned the `ndmin` parameter, as well as `atleast_1d` (there's also a 2d and 3d).  Look at the docs and code of `atleast_1d` to see how it reshapes various cases. e.g.

```
 if len(ary.shape) == 0 :
     result = ary.reshape(1)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see how to use the tuple to help in this example, but it's worthwhile to know.  I'm sort of getting used to the 1d array and can kind of see the appeal of distinguishing vectors from matrices, although I still haven't wrapped my head around the 0d version yet.

Comment: There are ways of indexing that don't reduce the dimension - `x1[[1]]`, `x1[:1]`, etc.

Comment: That output is not correct - `x[0,0][()]` is not an array

Comment: @Eric, now it is a `numpy.int32`.  I don't know why I posted `array(1)` last year; it looks like a copy-n-paste (from an earlier version)..  But my point remains, a `dtype` object acts like a 0d array.

Comment: I think you mean a `np.generic` object. There's a proposal to make `isinstance(np.int32, np.dtype)` true, but it's a long way off, and even then that wouldn't make `isinstance(np.int32(1), np.dtype)` true.